# Send as PDF add-on in plone not working

Tags: plone

I'm new to plone and im trying to get the send as PDF add on to work. I have added:

- pisa
- pyPdf
- html5lib
- reportlab

to the buildout file and have configured the `collective.sendaspdf` send as PDF add-on. Whenever I try click on the send as PDF option, it does nothing. Help will be appreciated.

The traceback in the error log has the following information:

```
Exception Value
    'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 8192: ordinal not in range(128)

Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
    Module jquery.pyproxy.plone, line 66, in _jquery
    Module collective.sendaspdf.browser.ajax, line 56, in show_send_form
    Module collective.sendaspdf.browser.ajax, line 44, in _show_send_form
    Module collective.sendaspdf.browser.base, line 237, in make_pdf
    Module collective.sendaspdf.browser.base, line 223, in generate_pdf_file
    Module collective.sendaspdf.transforms.pisa, line 16, in html_to_pdf

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 8192: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try to install wkhtmltopdf through build out by using bin/buildout after modifying the buildout.cfg file, I get the following error:

While:
  Installing.
Error: Missing option: buildout:parts
************** PICKED VERSIONS ***************
[versions]

******** */PICKED VERSIONS* **********

I have done everything it says in this link: https://github.com/vincent-psarga/collective.sendaspdf

I have made the following changes in my buildout file(buildout.cfg):

```
parts =
    instance
    zopepy
    zopeskel
    unifiedinstaller
    repozo
    backup
    chown
    wkhtmltopdf
    wkhtmltopdf_executable   

environment-vars =
    zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
    PYTHON_EGG_CACHE ${buildout:directory}/var/.python-eggs
    WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH ${buildout:directory}/wkhtmltopdf 

[wkhtmltopdf]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.download
url = http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2

[wkhtmltopdf_executable]
recipe = collective.recipe.cmd
on_install = true
on_update = true
cmds =
     cd ${buildout:directory}/parts/wkhtmltopdf
     mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 wkhtmltopdf
     chmod +x wkhtmltopdf
```

Can you please tell me what I did wrong?. Help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Comment: There are no errors in your error log at all? Are there any interesting lines in the instance-Z2.log access logfile?

Comment: The rotating circle which comes when something loads shows up for a second and disappears and yeah no other page activity. I can see nothing of interest in the instance-Z2.log file. I am not sure if I did the installation right. I have installed pisa,puPdf and the others that are listed above. how did you configure this add on?

Comment: I haven't; but if things go wrong you'll see an error message in the log; go to the control panel (site setup) and take a look if there is anything logged there. If so, edit your question and add the full traceback.

Comment: Added traceback information form the error log.

Comment: Thanks; I suspect there is a bug in that package, but now more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the main developer of Send as PDF. One simple question: do you really need to use Pisa/report lab ?

I've added it at the beginning of the tool development but the support for this PDF generator will be dropped soon (wkhtmltopdf works like a charm and it's a bit hard to maintain both supports).
If you look at the product's README, there is explanations for installing WKHtmlToPDF: https://github.com/vincent-psarga/collective.sendaspdf

I strongly suggest you to use this tool, there's more options for it than what you would have with Pisa.
If you really need Pisa/reportlab, I'll take a look at the issue anyway ;)

Cheers,
Vincent

Comment: Vincent. Thank you so much for the prompt reply. I just need the add on to work. I do not have a specific need for report lab. I have deployed Plone on Opensuse linux and I have tried setting up the add on but it does not work. I have tried to install the wkhtmltopdf by just using the buildout file. When I try the bin/buildout command to get it to work, I get an error message. I have edited the question and have added what happens when I try. Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I've reverted the edit, as per my comment in reply to Agi on my own answer. @Agi, please create a *new* Stack Overflow question with your new problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529879/cant-download-wkhtmltopdf-for-sendaspdf-add-on-in-plone . That is the link to the new question post that i created. Please have a look at it when time permits. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Looking over the source code I think you have hit a bug here.

The code expects the HTML being input to be a unicode string, but this is not the case for you, and re-encoding it to ASCII fails.

You'll need to file a bug report with your traceback in the [collective.sendaspdf issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/vincent-psarga/collective.sendaspdf/issues).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply Martijn. I have edited the question. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. THank you

Comment: @Agi: Please create a *new* post for a new question. I'll revert your current edit, it changes your question too much. On Stack Overflow we try to keep questions future-proof, so that others can benefit from the answers you received.