# cant download wkhtmltopdf for sendaspdf add on in Plone

Tags: plone

When I try to install wkhtmltopdf through build out by using bin/buildout after modifying the buildout.cfg file as suggested by Dan, I get the following error:

```
Updating wkhtmltopdf_executable.
mv: cannot stat `wkhtmltopdf-amd64': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `wkhtmltopdf': No such file or directory
Installing wkhtmltopdf.
wkhtmltopdf: Unable to extract the package /home/user/Plone/buildout-cache/downloads/94af137dfe94508c7d7bfab08214118c. Unknown format.
While:
  Installing wkhtmltopdf.
Error: Package extraction error
```

I have done everything it says in this link: https://github.com/vincent-psarga/collective.sendaspdf

My buildout file now looks like this:(buildout.cfg):

```
############################################
#
# Buildout Configuration File for Standalone Plone
# ------------------------------------------------
#
# After making changes in this configuration file,
# you should run bin/buildout to update the components.
# 
# ALWAYS back up all Plone/Zope data and components
# before changing configuration.
# 
# Running "bin/buildout" will update your installation,
# installing missing components as necessary.
# 
# Use "bin/buildout -n" to update many components here to the newest
# available releases.
# This will update the add-on products you've added in the eggs= lines.
# This will not, however, upgrade Plone itself (or anything else you've
# pinned with a version specification). To upgrade Plone itself, see the
# comments in "Plone Component Versions".
#
# Tutorial instructions for using zc.buildout for
# configuration management are available at:
# http://plone.org/documentation/tutorial/buildout
# Full details at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout
#
############################################


[buildout]

############################################
# Plone Component Versions
# ------------------------
# This version of the Unified Installer has the components of Plone 4 
# preloaded so that it can install without an Internet connection.
# If you want to update, uncomment the "http://..." line below,
# edit it to point to the current version URL, comment out the 
# "versions.cfg" line and run "bin/buildout" while attached to the 
# Internet. Generally, you only want to do that as part of a planned migration.
# Note that if you are updating components, you should also check the versions
# section at the end of this file, since recipes or components other than
# those of Zope and Plone may need updating at the same time.
#
extends = 
    base.cfg
    versions.cfg
    http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2-latest/versions.cfg

# If you change your Plone version, you'll also need to update
# the repository below.
find-links +=
    http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2

############################################
# Ports
# -----
# Specify the port on which your Zope installation
# will listen:
http-address = 8080


# If you try to start Zope as root, it will change user id to run as
# the effective user specified here. This user id must own the var directory
# of your buildout.
effective-user = user


############################################
# Eggs
# ----
# Add an indented line to the eggs section for any Python
# eggs or packages you wish to include.
#
eggs =
    Plone
    Pillow
    lxml
    pisa
    pyPdf
    html5lib
    reportlab 
    collective.quickupload
    Products.reflecto
    Products.ploneboard
    Products.EasyNewsletter
    collective.subscribablesections
    Products.CMFNotification
    Products.PloneSubscription
    plone.app.ldap
    plone.app.theming
    collective.groupspace.content
    collective.groupspace.mail
    collective.groupspace.workflow
    collective.groupspace.roles
    collective.sendaspdf
    ftw.dashboard.portlets.favourites
    quintagroup.dropdownmenu
    Products.Carousel
    Products.ContentWellPortlets
    quintagroup.theme.lite
    zettwerk.ui
    collective.kuputabs
    collective.tabr
    collective.zipfiletransport  


# Optional Functionality
# ----------------------
# Uncomment the indented lines to include these add-on products.
# Documentation on all of them, along with many more products,
# is available at
# http://plone.org/products/
#
# Example products:
# * LinguaPlone provides tools for building multi-lingual sites
# * PloneFormGen provides through-the-web form building
#
#    Products.LinguaPlone==4.1.1
#    Products.PloneFormGen==1.7.0
#
# Note that versions may be specified here or in the [versions]
# section below. You should always specify versions that you know
# are compatible with the Plone release and at an acceptable
# development level.
#
# Commonly used development tools:
# Several excellent development tools are included in the develop.cfg
# buildout extension. Read it to learn how to activate these tools.


############################################
# ZCML Slugs
# ----------
# Some eggs need ZCML slugs to tell Zope to
# use them. This is increasingly rare.
zcml =
#    plone.reload
     ftw.dashboard.portlets.favourites
     collective.kuputabs


############################################
# Development Eggs
# ----------------
# You can use paster to create "development eggs" to
# develop new products/themes. Put these in the src/
# directory.
# You will also need to add the egg names in the
# eggs section above, and may also need to add them
# to the zcml section.
#
# Provide the *paths* to the eggs you are developing here:
develop =
#    src/my.package


############################################
# Debug Mode
# ----------
# Change debug-mode to "on" to run in development mode.
# This will dramatically slow Plone.
# 
debug-mode = off
# Add-on developers should turn deprecation warnings on
deprecation-warnings = off
# change verbose-security to "on" for useful security errors while developing
verbose-security = off


############################################
# Backup Directory
# ----------------
# Sets the target directory for the bin/backup and bin/snapshotbackup
# commands. Default is inside this project's var directory, but ideally
# this should be on a separate volume or backup server.
# 
backups-dir=${buildout:directory}/var


############################################
# Initial User
# ------------
# This is the user id and password that will be used to create the initial 
# user id that will allow you to log in and create a Plone site. This only
# sets the initial password; it will not allow you to change an already 
# existing password. If you change the admin password via the web interface,
# the one below will no longer be valid.
# If you find yourself locked out of your Zope/Python installation, you may
# add an emergency user via "bin/plonectl adduser".
user=admin:*******


############################################
# Parts Specification
#--------------------
# Specifies the components that should be included in the buildout.
# All the basics are in the base.cfg extension; you may add your
# own if you need them at the end of this file.
parts =
    instance
    zopepy
    zopeskel
    unifiedinstaller
    repozo
    backup
    chown 
    wkhtmltopdf
    wkhtmltopdf_executable

############################################
# Environment Variables
# ---------------------
# Some of the behavior of your Zope/Plone instances are controlled with OS
# environment variables. You may set those here in a key / value format.
# Some common settings:
#    * TZ allows you to set a time zone for systems where it's not
#      automatically available.
#    * zope_i18n_compile_mo_files allows for automatic compilation of
#      missing translation files (may slow startup).
#    * zope_i18n_allowed_languages allows you to limit the available
#      translations.
#    * PYTHON_EGG_CACHE determines where zipped python packages are unpacked
#      for use.
[instance]
environment-vars =
    zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
    PYTHON_EGG_CACHE ${buildout:directory}/var/.python-eggs
    WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH ${buildout:directory}/wkhtmltopdf


[wkhtmltopdf]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.download
url = http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2

[wkhtmltopdf_executable]
recipe = collective.recipe.cmd
on_install = true
on_update = true
cmds =
     cd ${buildout:directory}/parts/wkhtmltopdf
     mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 wkhtmltopdf
     chmod +x wkhtmltopdf

############################################
# Versions Specification
# ----------------------
# Version information supplied here will "pin" Python packages to a particular
# version number, even when you use the "newest" flag running buildout.
# Specifying versions for all packages is a good idea and can prevent
# accidental changes when you add new packages to your buildout.
# Note that versions specified here will override those specified earlier
# in the configuration, including those from the Plone and Zope version
# config files.
#
[versions]
Cheetah = 2.2.1
Pillow = 1.7.6
Products.DocFinderTab = 1.0.5
ZopeSkel = 2.21.2
collective.recipe.backup = 2.4
plone.recipe.command = 1.1
plone.recipe.unifiedinstaller = 4.1
ftw.dashboard.portlets.favourites = 2.0
lxml = 2.3.4
```

Vincet: This is my base.cfg file

```
######################################################
# Base Configuration; used by both standalone and zeo,
# which extend it.
# ---------------------------------------------------

# Buildout instructions in this file are
# usually only changed by experienced developers.
#
# Beyond here there be dragons!

[buildout]
eggs-directory=../buildout-cache/eggs
download-cache=../buildout-cache/downloads

# Don't download new things unless needed to satisfy dependencies.
# Override this on the command line with the "-n" flag.
newest = false

# Pick final releases over newer development releases when it's
# possible to do so and still fulfil requirements. Note that explicit
# version specifications will override this preference.
prefer-final = true

versions = versions

# Add additional egg download sources here. dist.plone.org contains archives
# of Plone packages.
find-links =
    http://dist.plone.org
    http://download.zope.org/ppix/
    http://download.zope.org/distribution/
    http://effbot.org/downloads

# unzip all eggs for easier debugging
unzip = true

# Load the DumpPickedVersions extension, which will notify
# you of versions picked by buildout that were not specifically
# pinned. 
extensions = buildout.dumppickedversions


[instance]
# Use this section to install and configure a Zope operating
# instance.
# For options see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
# The line below sets only the initial password. It will not change an
# existing password.
user = ${buildout:user}
http-address = ${buildout:http-address}
# if we try to start as root, Zope will switch to the user below
effective-user = ${buildout:effective-user}
# change debug-mode to "on" to run in development mode
debug-mode = ${buildout:debug-mode}
# change verbose-security to "on" for detailed security
# errors while developing
verbose-security = ${buildout:verbose-security}
# change deprecation-warnings to "on" to get log warnings
# for deprecated usages.
deprecation-warnings = ${buildout:deprecation-warnings}
blob-storage = ${buildout:directory}/var/blobstorage

# If you want Zope to know about any additional eggs, list them here.
# e.g. eggs = ${buildout:eggs} my.package
eggs =
    ${buildout:eggs}

# If you want to register ZCML slugs for any packages, list them here.
# e.g. zcml = my.package my.other.package
zcml = ${buildout:zcml}

products = ${buildout:directory}/products

# You may also control the environment variables for the instance.
environment-vars = ${buildout:environment-vars}


[zopepy]
# installs a zopepy python interpreter that runs with your
# full Zope environment
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
interpreter = zopepy
scripts = zopepy


[chown]
# This recipe is used to set permissions for root mode installs
# For options see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.command
recipe = plone.recipe.command
command =echo Dummy references to force this to execute after referenced parts
    echo ${backup:location} ${unifiedinstaller:sudo-command}
    chmod 600 .installed.cfg
    find ${buildout:directory}/var -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
    chmod 744 ${buildout:directory}/bin/*
update-command = ${chown:command}


[unifiedinstaller]
# This recipe installs the plonectl script and a few other convenience
# items.
# For options see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.unifiedinstaller
recipe = plone.recipe.unifiedinstaller
user = ${buildout:user}
primary-port = ${buildout:http-address}
sudo-command = 


[repozo]
# This recipe builds the repozo script for non-zeo installations.
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ZODB3
scripts = repozo


[backup]
# This recipe builds the backup, restore and snapshotbackup commands.
# For options see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.backup
recipe = collective.recipe.backup
location = ${buildout:backups-dir}/backups
snapshotlocation = ${buildout:backups-dir}/snapshotbackups








[zopeskel]
# installs paster and Zopeskel
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ZopeSkel
    Paste
    PasteDeploy
    PasteScript
    ${buildout:eggs}
```

This is my versions.cfg file:

```
# http://dist.plone.org/release/4.1.4/versions.cfg

[buildout]
extends = 
    zopeapp-versions.cfg
    zope-versions.cfg
#    http://download.zope.org/zopetoolkit/index/1.0.5/zopeapp-versions.cfg
#    http://download.zope.org/Zope2/index/2.13.12/versions.cfg

[versions]
# Zope overrides
# Products.BTreeFolder2 2.13.4 causes a regression
Products.BTreeFolder2 = 2.13.3

# Buildout infrastructure
buildout.dumppickedversions = 0.5
collective.recipe.omelette = 0.12
mr.developer = 1.18
plone.recipe.alltests = 1.2
plone.recipe.zope2instance = 4.1.9
plone.recipe.zeoserver = 1.2.2
distribute = 0.6.24
setuptools = 0.6c11
z3c.coverage = 1.2.0
z3c.ptcompat = 1.0
z3c.template = 1.4.0

# External dependencies
Markdown = 2.0.3
PIL = 1.1.6
Unidecode = 0.04.1
elementtree = 1.2.7-20070827-preview
feedparser = 5.0.1
mailinglogger = 3.3.3
python-dateutil = 1.5
python-openid = 2.2.5
simplejson = 2.1.6

# Plone release
Plone                                 = 4.1.4
Products.ATContentTypes               = 2.1.6
Products.ATReferenceBrowserWidget     = 3.0
Products.Archetypes                   = 1.7.12
Products.CMFActionIcons               = 2.1.3
Products.CMFCalendar                  = 2.2.2
Products.CMFCore                      = 2.2.5
Products.CMFDefault                   = 2.2.2
Products.CMFDiffTool                  = 2.0
Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI            = 4.0.2
Products.CMFEditions                  = 2.1.7
Products.CMFFormController            = 3.0.2
Products.CMFPlacefulWorkflow          = 1.5.6
Products.CMFPlone                     = 4.1.4
Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool        = 3.0.5
Products.CMFTestCase                  = 0.9.11
Products.CMFTopic                     = 2.2.1
Products.CMFUid                       = 2.2.1
Products.contentmigration             = 2.0.3
Products.DCWorkflow                   = 2.2.4
Products.ExtendedPathIndex            = 2.9
Products.ExternalEditor               = 1.0
Products.GenericSetup                 = 1.6.5
Products.Marshall                     = 2.1.1
Products.MimetypesRegistry            = 2.0.3
Products.PasswordResetTool            = 2.0.7
Products.PlacelessTranslationService  = 2.0.3
Products.PloneLanguageTool            = 3.2.4
Products.PlonePAS                     = 4.0.11
Products.PloneTestCase                = 0.9.13
Products.PluggableAuthService         = 1.7.7
Products.PluginRegistry               = 1.3
Products.PortalTransforms             = 2.0.7
Products.ResourceRegistries           = 2.0.6
Products.SecureMailHost               = 1.1.2
Products.TinyMCE                      = 1.2.10
Products.ZopeVersionControl           = 1.1.3
Products.ZSQLMethods                  = 2.13.4
Products.i18ntestcase                 = 1.2
Products.kupu                         = 1.5.0
Products.statusmessages               = 4.0
Products.validation                   = 2.0
archetypes.kss                        = 1.7.1
archetypes.referencebrowserwidget     = 2.4.9
archetypes.schemaextender             = 2.1.1
borg.localrole                        = 3.0.2
collective.monkeypatcher              = 1.0.1
collective.testcaselayer              = 1.3
collective.z3cform.datetimewidget     = 1.0.5
five.customerize                      = 1.0.2
five.formlib                          = 1.0.4
five.globalrequest                    = 1.0
five.localsitemanager                 = 2.0.5
kss.core                              = 1.6.3
plone.app.blob                        = 1.5.1
plone.app.caching                     = 1.0.1
plone.app.content                     = 2.0.7
plone.app.contentmenu                 = 2.0.5
plone.app.contentrules                = 2.1.4
plone.app.controlpanel                = 2.1.3
plone.app.customerize                 = 1.2.2
plone.app.discussion                  = 2.1.3
plone.app.folder                      = 1.0.4
plone.app.form                        = 2.0.5
plone.app.i18n                        = 2.0.1
plone.app.imaging                     = 1.0.5
plone.app.iterate                     = 2.1.4
plone.app.jquerytools                 = 1.3.1
plone.app.kss                         = 1.6.2
plone.app.layout                      = 2.1.13
plone.app.linkintegrity               = 1.4.4
plone.app.locales                     = 4.0.11
plone.app.openid                      = 2.0.2
plone.app.portlets                    = 2.1.7
plone.app.redirector                  = 1.1.2
plone.app.registry                    = 1.0.1
plone.app.testing                     = 4.0.2
plone.app.upgrade                     = 1.1.5
plone.app.users                       = 1.1.3
plone.app.uuid                        = 1.0
plone.app.viewletmanager              = 2.0.2
plone.app.vocabularies                = 2.1.5
plone.app.workflow                    = 2.0.6
plone.app.z3cform                     = 0.5.7
plone.autoform                        = 1.0
plone.browserlayer                    = 2.1.1
plone.cachepurging                    = 1.0.3
plone.caching                         = 1.0
plone.contentrules                    = 2.0.1
plone.fieldsets                       = 2.0.1
plone.folder                          = 1.0.1
plone.i18n                            = 2.0
plone.indexer                         = 1.0
plone.intelligenttext                 = 2.0.1
plone.keyring                         = 2.0
plone.locking                         = 2.0.3
plone.memoize                         = 1.1.1
plone.openid                          = 2.0
plone.outputfilters                   = 1.1
plone.portlet.collection              = 2.0.4
plone.portlet.static                  = 2.0.1
plone.portlets                        = 2.0.2
plone.protect                         = 2.0
plone.registry                        = 1.0
plone.reload                          = 2.0
plone.scale                           = 1.2.2
plone.session                         = 3.5
plone.stringinterp                    = 1.0.5
plone.supermodel                      = 1.0.3
plone.testing                         = 4.0.3
plone.theme                           = 2.1
plone.transformchain                  = 1.0.2
plone.uuid                            = 1.0.2
plone.z3cform                         = 0.7.8
plonetheme.classic                    = 1.1.2
plonetheme.sunburst                   = 1.1.6
wicked                                = 1.1.9
z3c.autoinclude                       = 0.3.4
z3c.batching                          = 1.1.0
z3c.caching                           = 2.0a1
z3c.form                              = 2.5.1
z3c.formwidget.query                  = 0.5
z3c.zcmlhook                          = 1.0b1
zope.globalrequest                    = 1.0
```

Can you please tell me what I did wrong?. Help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the instructions at https://github.com/vincent-psarga/collective.sendaspdf works for me.

**Edit**: Ah, now that you've posted your entire `buildout.cfg` I can see the problem. The `parts =` section must be part of the `[buildout]` stanza. It is currently under `[wkhtmltopdf_executable]`.

Same goes for setting the initial user. Note that you've included the admin password, so if that really is the password I would change it now!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have added the entire script. If I am correct, doing it this way does not need any other installations of wkhtmltopdf files. Or do we need to install wkhtmltopdf from an external site again?. Please let me know when time permits

Comment: @Agi I've edited my answer. You are correct: doing it this way means that you do not need any other installations of wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: I have made a backup before making the changes. Once I made the necessary changes, it gives me the following error when I try to restart the instance.

Comment: Error: error opening file /home/user/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/zope.conf: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/zope.conf'
For help, use bin/instance -h

Comment: I could not even rebuild the buildout. I got an error message that is too big for a comment. However the first few lines are as follows:

Comment: Uninstalling instance.
While:
  Installing.
  Uninstalling instance.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1683, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)

Comment: @Agi Ouch, sorry to hear that. Sounds like you might need to reset the buildout by removing the `.installed.cfg` file. Maybe the `parts/` directory too. Then do `./bin/buildout` again.

Comment: could you paste the base.cfg and versions.cfg files located with your buildout.cfg file in your initial post too ? And update the buildout.cfg file with the changes based on Dan Jacka answer ? (in case removing .installed and parts does not work)

Comment: I have made the necessary changes in the buildout file as suggested by dan jacka and when i try bin/build out, I get the following message:    Updating wkhtmltopdf_executable.
mv: cannot stat `wkhtmltopdf-amd64': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `wkhtmltopdf': No such file or directory
Installing wkhtmltopdf.
wkhtmltopdf: Unable to extract the package /home/user/Plone/buildout-cache/downloads/94af137dfe94508c7d7bfab08214118c. Unknown format.
While:
  Installing wkhtmltopdf.
Error: Package extraction error

Comment: I have changed the question and have added what my buildout.cfg , base.cfg and versions.cfg files look like. Please let me know when time permits

Comment: @Agi The most recent error suggests that the buildout was interrupted before the wkhtmltopdf tar.bz2 was fully downloaded. Delete the file or directory mentioned in the error message (the one in `buildout-cache/downloads/`). Also do `find /home/user/Plone -name wkhtmltopdf\*.tar.\*` and delete any file found. Then `./bin/buildout` again.

Comment: @DanJacka. Tried doing that. However whenever i do a buildout, it somehow recreates the files i deleted.

Comment: @Agi Yes, that is the idea. We want buildout to create those files afresh. Things I would try now: 1) create a fresh Plone install (looks like you've used the [Unified Installer](https://plone.org/products/plone/releases/4.1.4)) and make only the wkhtmltopdf modifications; 2) Follow http://www.martinaspeli.net/articles/buildout-hard-reset (though [make sure all your egg versions are pinned first](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/buildout.dumppickedversions/)); 3) Ask in [#plone IRC](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/ask-for-help#irc) and direct them to this question.